# System.Configuration in a custom installer class

Tags: c#, windows-installer

I have a .NET 2.0 project winforms app. I have another setup installer project.

I've added a custom installer class to the winforms app, that I want to pull some app configuration values to display/allow the user to change during the setup MSI running.

I'm trying to use this example, as it's well documented and makes sense:
http://raquila.com/software/configure-app-config-application-settings-during-msi-install/

The probelm I'm running into is that "System.Configuration" is not giving me the "Configuration" object. I have the following code in place:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Configuration.Install;
using System.Configuration;


namespace BadgeReader
{
    [RunInstaller(true)]
    public partial class InstallerSettings : System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    {
        public InstallerSettings()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);

            //get the custom settings

            //System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();

             System.Configuration
            //Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(exePath);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the last commented line to work, and it's not working... I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a reference to `System.Configuration.dll`

Comment: Oh my god. I swear I had done that. I swear I had checked that.... I swear I looked and re-looked.